# sql orden de valores nulos al final

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Quiero ordenar principalmente por 2 fechas a la vez; fecha de reingreso y hora. ¿Las fechas se ordenan correctamente, pero si agrego al final la opción de nulls last; los valores nulos me siguen apareciendo al inicio y yo quiero que estos aparezcan hasta el final, alguna idea?

```
select id_solicitud,solicitante,departamento,fecha_solicitud,hora_solicitud,fecha_entrega,hora_entrega,fecha_reingreso,hora_reingreso,
        comentarios,descripcion,expedientes.id_expediente,clave,propietario,fraccionamiento,cajon,pasillo,archivero,area from expedientes 
        JOIN solicitudes ON expedientes.id_expediente=solicitudes.id_expediente
         JOIN estatus ON solicitudes.id_estatus=estatus.id_estatus where fecha_reingreso is not null or solicitudes.id_estatus=2 
        or solicitudes.id_estatus=4 order by (solicitudes.fecha_reingreso,hora_reingreso) desc nulls last
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que aplicar `NULLS LAST` a cada column por separado. Por ejemplo:

```
with 
d as (
  select '2022-01-01 12:34:56'::timestamp as t
  union all select '2022-01-25 12:34:56'::timestamp as t
  union all select null
)
select * from d order by t desc nulls last
```